# How to keep the active menu item highlighted when visiting pages in ASP.Net MVC 5 application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

So, I have one ASP.Net MVC 5 application. In that one of page hasfour menu items. When page loads first menu item is selected by default (so it should be highlighted as soon as the page loads). And now as soon as user clicks on any other menu, that other menu should be in highlighted stage, so that user knows which menu he is currently on. Below is my attempt:

**My thinking:**

a. add a click event on the ul tag.

b. when clicked find "active" class inside ul tag and remove it.

c. now add active class to the source of click event (which means the li tag on which user clicked).

**Issue:**

> The selected/clicked menu gets highlighted for a second, and then
>   automatically first menu gets highlighted. So as soon as the whole
>   page corresponding to the newly clicked menu item reloads the first
>   menu item gets highlighted back.

**My Attempt**

P.S: This is a partial View, And all redirects will load this partial view **afresh**.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li class="active setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Resume")" class="btn btn-block">My Resume </a>
        </li>
        <li class="setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "CoverLetter")" class="btn btn-block">My Cover Letter </a>
        </li>
        <li class="setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-block">My Account </a>
        </li>
        <li class="setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn  btn-block">Get Rewards </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}

<script>
// ATTEMPT 1
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
        $('ul li').removeAttr('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });

// ATTEMPT 2
    //$("li").click(function () {
    //    //$("ul li").removeClass("active");
    //    $(this).addClass("active");
    //});
</script>
```

**EDIT 1**

So the problem is as the page gets redirected. The active tag again gets appened to the first menu item when entire DOM gets reloaded **because all the landing pages use the same partial view**.

Comment: You are almost there. Just have to change a little bit of the code. I created a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x82a1eoa/) for you check this out

Comment: fiddle link is broken. I am not able to open it

Comment: updated. try it again :)

Comment: The first page gets the colour is normal, because everytime you click a tab, it adds class active and then it does a page redirect, doesn't matter which page you are one(resume, coverletter, home etc), they are using the same template, and in that template, the first menu item, which is the resume has the active class on it.

Comment: @Mindless:Oh.. and as soon as the whole page reloads the active tag again gets added

Comment: You have to think of a different approach, write a custom HtmlHelper class

Comment: @Mindless:  Since this is a partial view. Every page "all four link" when gets redirected loads this partial view. Basically keeps this partial view intact

Comment: Yes exactly, that's why you should build the html differently, if the page url is the same as the link url, append active class on it and build the html, i will write an answer to this

Comment: @Mindless: I am a beginner, so I don't know much, but I will definitely try. But thanks for atleast letting me know, why all the jquery hacks were not working. ;)

Comment: You need to read the current request and set the class based on that

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Can you kindly guide me a little more. if I implement this, it will be a nice learning experience for me

Comment: There are a lot of different ways you can do this, including creating a `HtmlHelper` extension method or using javascript. It depends how you want to do it.

Comment: I want to do it in simple way. I don't want to use Htmlhelper, they are scary. I want to learn javascript way

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I can add more details of my code, if my question is missing some essential points. But all I have are basic controller actions in the backend.

Comment: Can I use viewbag or something to pass the clicked page, and do some stuffs. Just curious. I am not sure. just thinking.

Comment: Yes you could (in conjunction with some javascript), but an extension method would be the best method (similar to the answer Mindless has given, but that can be improved)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151554/discussion-between-unbreakable-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: @Mindless: Even though I did not mention anything about partial view. I don't know how you were able to figure out that my issue was related to partial view and not relaed to jquery and all.  very smart. :) I edited my question with partial view details and all after your comments.

Comment: @Unbreakable Well, that's what a well structured question leads to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everytime you click on a link, it does a page redirect, and it doesn't matter what changes you've made with jQuery, it always fetch this partial view, and in this partial view, you have active class on the first link, that is why it always highlights the first link.

What you have to do is write an HtmlHelper that will add the class "active" to current link on each page load. Create a folder called Helpers under your project and add a custom HtmlHelper class.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class ActiveMenuHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string areaName)
    {
        var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var currentArea = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

        var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
        {
            //InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString()
            InnerHtml = "<a href=\"" + new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext).Action(actionName, controllerName, new { area = areaName }).ToString() + "\">" + linkText + "</a>"
        };

        if (String.Equals(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && String.Equals(actionName, currentAction, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            builder.AddCssClass("active");

        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then in your partial view:

```
@using YourProjectName.Helpers

<ul>
    @Html.MenuLink("Resume", "Index", "Resume", "" )
    @Html.MenuLink("Cover Letter", "Index", "CoverLetter", "" )
</ul>
```

You might not need the **area**, that is why you can leave it blank, i put it in here just in case.

Comment: This is a solution that will take some time for me to comprehend. I will definitely try  this as I will learn alot from this. I will try this and comment/accept/ask accordingly.

Comment: This can be improved by adding arguments for route values and html attributes, and by using `htmlHelper.ActionLink(...)` to generate the `InnerHtml` (and of course creating various overloads)

Comment: Stephen is the master at this, he helped me alot, you are in safe hands haha

Comment: @Mindless: I am yet to try your solution. I will mostly try it tonight and will accept it accordingly. In the mean time I tried the below solution by `JF-Mechs` and it worked. What's your take on that solution. Is that a good way too?

Comment: Also, in your solution you have kept "area", "controller" and "action" text hardcoded. So, those strings are needed to bel ike that by the framework itself right? It has nothing to do with any of our code right?

Comment: @Mindless   Tried your solution now. Worked in first go. Thank you so much.

Comment: Read the comments by @StephenMuecke of using built in `actionlink`. I will try that too. It will remove all the extra noise from code. :)

Comment: @Unbreakable, Yea, now that i remembered it, i think the reason why i didn't use actionlink is because i have to create a link like this <a href=""><i class="" /></a>, i modified my code to remove <i class="" /> inside, but as Stephen pointed out, actionlink is preferred. you can see that i commented out actionlink as i was using the previously, i forgot about it.

Comment: @Unbreakable and regarding your hardcode question, yes

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sir, I have some button such as "create new" in landing pages of left menu items. But when I used to visit index page then correct tab was getting highlighted, but when I clicked on Create New button inside it, then tab highlighting vanished, because the action won't match now in HTML Helper. So  I removed the Action matching element from the HTML Helper, so that as long as controller name is same, I just added the active tab. Hope I did the right thing

Comment: new code  `if (String.Equals(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            builder.AddCssClass("active");`

Comment: @Unbreakable, That would only work so long as your menu never contains more that one item from the same controller. A better solution may be to provide `null` to the `actionName` and then test if its provided or not (and if not, use the code in your previous comment)

Answer (score 6):

Try adding this to your shared view . normally "_Layout".

```
@{ 
    string pageUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToString();
}
```

and instead of adding "active" class from the html markups, add conditional statement that will check the pageUrl just like the code below.

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
        <li class="@(pageUrl.ToLower().Contains("/index/Resume") ? "active" : string.Empty) setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Resume")" class="btn btn-block">My Resume </a>
        </li>
        <li class="@(pageUrl.ToLower().Contains("/index/CoverLetter") ? "active" : string.Empty) setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "CoverLetter")" class="btn btn-block">My Cover Letter </a>
        </li>
        <li class="@(pageUrl.ToLower().Contains("/index/Home") ? "active" : string.Empty) setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn btn-block">My Account </a>
        </li>
        <li class="@(pageUrl.ToLower().Contains("/index/Home") ? "active" : string.Empty) setBtnMargin">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="btn  btn-block">Get Rewards </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: So your solution worked, so basically we are adding the active class when the actual landing page is getting loaded. To be honest it might not be one the best solution. but it works like a charm. :) Thank you. :)

Comment: slight edit is required. The text after `.contains` all needs to be in lower case. /index/Resume -> /index/resume (all lowered)

Comment: @Unbreakable yes, exactly you only add the active class when the page loaded. Its alright, This was just a quick fix I made for you and for all those who might need it and so I'm leaving it here.  Good luck mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add document ready function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function () {
        $('ul li').removeAttr('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: all these solution will not worlk for me. because i am using partial view. And for every page redirection the entire DOM gets relaoded, along with the partial view. So, your code will remove the active and will add active tag to the correct menu element. but after than the entire page gets reloaded. and that will again set the first menu element to active.

Comment: and that is the reason, the actual menu when clicked gets highlighted just for a second. but when the entire DOM gets relaoded. the first menu item gets highlighted. Because each of the page redirection is using the same partial view which has "active" tag on the first menu element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample one. it works for me. :) :)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).load(function(){
            var x = window.location.href;
                $('ul a[href="'+x+'"]').each(function() {
                    if(x == window.location.href){
                        $('ul li').removeClass('active');
                        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
                    } 
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach, leveraging the fact that I use a load script for each partial view to load data into DataTables on that view.

I started by added an "id" to each of the menu items.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="Index"><a asp-page="/Index">Reportables</a></li>
    <li id="TaskAssayExclusion"><a asp-page="/TaskAssayExclusion">Task Assay Exclusions</a></li>
    <li id="SpecimenSite"><a asp-page="/SpecimenSite">Specimen Site</a></li>
    <li id="SnomedCT"><a asp-page="/SnomedCT">Snomed CT</a></li>
    <li id="Loinc"><a asp-page="/Loinc">LOINC</a></li>
    <li id="Search"><a asp-page="/Search">Search Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

At the bottom of each partial view I have a snippet of JavaScript that gets executed when that view loads.  An example of the snippet for the Index page is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function partialIndexModelScript() {
        $('li#Index').addClass('menu_item_active');
        filterLoadComplete = false;
        selectLoadComplete = false;
        loadReportableResultData();
    }
</script>
```

In my main JavaScript file, near the end of the `$(document).ready()` function I use 'typeof' to execute the relevant JavaScript snippet.

```
if (typeof partialIndexModelScript !== "undefined") partialIndexModelScript();
if (typeof partialSpecimenSiteModelScript !== "undefined") partialSpecimenSiteModelScript();
if (typeof partialNormalcyModelScript !== "undefined") partialNormalcyModelScript();
if (typeof partialSnomedCTModelScript !== "undefined") partialSnomedCTModelScript();
if (typeof partialLoincModelScript !== "undefined") partialLoincModelScript();
if (typeof partialTaskAssayExclusionModelScript !== "undefined") partialTaskAssayExclusionModelScript();
if (typeof partialSearchModelScript !== "undefined") partialSearchModelScript();
```

And finally the CSS which is nearly identical to the :hover CSS except that 
 
I've included the `font-weight: bolder !important` to really make the selected menu item stand out.

```
.menu_item_active {
    color: #B8B7DA !important;
    background-color: #514689 !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    font-weight: bolder !important;
}
```

[The final result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZq94.png)