# Set Menu to class active based on selection in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am having an issue with menu selection in my application. Basically, I have a side menu that gets populated dynamically from the database.

```
foreach (var item in Model.SideMenuItemsList)
{
    <li id="@item.Id" class="@Html.IsSelected(actions: "Index, Profile", controllers: "Employee, Policy")">
        <a href="@{if (item.SubMenus.Count > 0) { <text> #exampledropdownDropdown </text>} else { @item.Url} } " @{if (item.SubMenus.Count > 0) { <text> aria-expanded="false" data-toggle="collapse" </text>  } }> <i class="@item.Icon"></i>@item.Name</a>
        <ul id="exampledropdownDropdown" class="collapse list-unstyled">

            @foreach (var subMenus in item.SubMenus)
            {
                <li><a href="@subMenus.Url"><i class="@subMenus.Icon"></i>@subMenus.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
```

I have use a custom Html Helper to make the selection of a menu if I am on a specific page. The Html Helper is as follows:

```
public static string IsSelected(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string controllers, string actions, string cssClass = "active")
{
    string currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;
    string currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string;

    IEnumerable<string> acceptedActions = (actions ?? currentAction).Split(',');
    IEnumerable<string> acceptedControllers = (controllers ?? currentController).Split(',');

    return acceptedActions.Contains(currentAction) && acceptedControllers.Contains(currentController) ?
        cssClass : String.Empty;
}
```

It sets the menu class to `active`. But the issue here is that, all my menu are being set to active. How can I work this out to make only the current one active based on the page that I am? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Some help [Here](http://www.sweet-web-design.com/wordpress/how-to-add-active-class-to-menu-tab-in-asp-net-mvc/2954/),  From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603694/6085193)

What you have to do is write an HtmlHelper that will add the class "active" to current link on each page load. Create a folder called Helpers under your project and add a custom HtmlHelper class.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class ActiveMenuHelper
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, string areaName)
    {
        var currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        var currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var currentArea = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"];

        var builder = new TagBuilder("li")
        {
            //InnerHtml = htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName).ToHtmlString()
            InnerHtml = "<a href=\"" + new UrlHelper(htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext).Action(actionName, controllerName, new { area = areaName }).ToString() + "\">" + linkText + "</a>"
        };

        if (String.Equals(controllerName, currentController, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && String.Equals(actionName, currentAction, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            builder.AddCssClass("active");

        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then in your partial view:

```
@using YourProjectName.Helpers

<ul>
    @Html.MenuLink("Resume", "Index", "Resume", "" )
    @Html.MenuLink("Cover Letter", "Index", "CoverLetter", "" )
</ul>
```